# Properly handling backend calls with nodejs (sync/async?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

So I've read quite some questions here and articles about how to use nodejs with async callbacks etc. And I think I've understood that I have to get rid of the thought to write my application as a series of synchronous statements but instead as a loose collection of callbacks call callbacks.

Now my scenario:
I am using nodejs to handle a request that in turn opens a connection to a backend server to fetch markup. This markup is essential for this request to make sense. So I want to return the response to the client only when the backend returned the markup. This sounds to me like a usecase for a synchronous call. But when I open the connection to the backend, I don't know how to make my current request wait for the backend request to return.
And if there is some nifty solution to send stuff to the client after the response has been submitted, how do I do that then?

Answer (score 1):

No, opening a connection, sending a request, and waiting for a response is an inherently **asynchronous** task. You want your server do other things during that (e.g. handling this task multiple times in parallel), so you don't want to block with a synchronous call.

Use a callback instead; basically something like

```
on("frontend-request", function(request, response) {
    fetch("backend-markup", function(markup) {
        response.write(markup);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't *have* to be a synchronous call and, in fact, *shouldn't* be - if the call itself is naturally asynchronous then all you need to do is return the response from inside the callback

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    someAsyncCall(function(html) {
        res.write(html);
        res.end();
    });
});
```

The request will block until `end()` is called meaning nothing will be returned until your markup is returned. Meanwhile, the process is free to handle subsequent requests whilst waiting for `someAsyncCall` to complete.